# netbeans webservice greek characters

Tags: java, web-services

I created a web application in NetBeans and there was a simple hello world web service which was like this.

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
public String sayHello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
    return "Hello " + txt + " !";
  }
}
```

When i deploy and try to test it if i type a greek word i get this exception :

```
WS00041: Service invocation threw an exception with message : 
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: 
Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.; Refer to the server log for more details

Exceptions details : javax.xml.transform.TransformerException:   
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException:
Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.
```

I tried to find a solution with changing the encoding but with no result, any solution for this?

Comment: Where do you get the exception - client or server? What does the full stack trace look like?

Comment: i am not sure, here is the full exception http://pasted.co/365fb987

Comment: Please put the stack trace *in the question*, as well as specifying that it happens on the server, not the client - by the looks of it. How are you invoking the web service? We need more context.